# Нужен слайдер как на skype.com

Tags: jquery

Поискал, ничего подходящего (кроссбраузерного) не нашел. :(

Answer (score 1):

[jQuery Cycle Plugin](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/cycle/) - пользуюсь им, он достаточно многофункционален, есть урезанная лайт версия.

Answer (score 1):

Вот есть похожий [слайдер](http://www.yanajy.com/upload/jquery/slideshow/slideshow.html), опустите стрелочки вниз к основной пагинации, передвинете их влево и будет точно так же как на skype.com